# Trigger event in jQuery with params

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using the `django-autocomplete-light` library to have a `ModelSelect2` field in my form. I need to externally change the currently selected item. The library has a following code to handle the `select2:selecting` event.

```
document.addEventListener('dal-init-function', function () {
    ...
    yl.registerFunction( 'select2', function ($, element) {

        $element.on('select2:selecting', function (e) {
            var data = e.params.args.data;

            if (data.create_id !== true)
                return;

            e.preventDefault();
            ...
```

I have developed the following line to trigger the event:

```
        params = {
            "params": {
                "args": {
                    "data": {
                        id: "324856",
                        selected_text: "ABERTAMY (Karlovy Vary)",
                        text: "ABERTAMY (Karlovy Vary)"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        $( "#id_hlavni_katastr" ).trigger( "select2:selecting", params )
```

However, the params are not passed and I have searched the whole `e` variable without finding the data. How to update the trigger event so it passes on the params correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$element.on('select2:selecting', function (e) { ... }`, you can replace it with `$element.on('select2:selecting', function (e, customParrams) { ... }`. The parameters you passed when using the `trigger` method will be populated in the `customParrams` variable. Here's an example:

```js
$('input').on('click', function (e, customParams) {
  console.log(customParams.params.args.data);
});

var params = {
  "params": {
    "args": {
      "data": {
        id: "324856",
        selected_text: "ABERTAMY (Karlovy Vary)",
        text: "ABERTAMY (Karlovy Vary)"
      }
    }
  }
};

$('input').trigger('click', params);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden">
```

For more examples you can visit the jQuery documentation on the [following page](https://api.jquery.com/on/#example-5).